# localstorage setitem for every block in <table>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this contenteditable table on my website.

```
      <table>
        <tr class="top">
          <th></th>
          <th>Monday</th>
          <th>Tuesday</th>
          <th class="wed">Wednesday</th>
          <th>Thursday</th>
          <th>Friday</th>
          <th>Saturday</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="noedit" colspan="3"></td>
          <td class="noedit" id="block-b">Meeting</td>
          <td class="noedit" colspan="3"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Period 1</th>
          <td id="p1d1" tabindex=1></td>
          <td id="p1d2" tabindex=2></td>
          <td id="p1d3" tabindex=3></td>
          <td id="p1d4" tabindex=4></td>
          <td id="p1d5" tabindex=5></td>
          <td id="p1d6" tabindex=6></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Period 2</th>
          <td id="p2d1"></td>
          <td id="p2d2"></td>
          <td id="p2d3"></td>
          <td id="p2d4"></td>
          <td id="p2d5"></td>
          <td id="p2d6"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th></th>
          <td class="noedit">Chapel</td>
          <td class="noedit">Meeting or Advisory</td>
          <td class="noedit">Advisory</td>
          <td class="noedit">Class Meeting</td>
          <td class="noedit">or Advisory</td>
          <td class="noedit">Break</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Period 3</th>
          <td id="p3d1"></td>
          <td id="p3d2"></td>
          <td id="p3d3"></td>
          <td id="p3d4"></td>
          <td id="p3d5"></td>
          <td id="p3d6"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Period 4</th>
          <td id="p4d1"></td>
          <td id="p4d2"></td>
          <td id="p4d3"></td>
          <td id="p4d4"></td>
          <td id="p4d5"></td>
          <td id="p4d6"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Period 5a</th>
          <td id="p5ad1"></td>
          <td id="p5ad2"></td>
          <td class="noedit" rowspan="4"></td>
          <td id="p5ad4"></td>
          <td id="p5ad5"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Period 5b</th>
          <td id="p5bd1"></td>
          <td id="p5bd2"></td>
          <td id="p5bd4"></td>
          <td id="p5bd5"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Period 6</th>
          <td id="p6d1"></td>
          <td id="p6d2"></td>
          <td id="p6d4"></td>
          <td id="p6d5"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Period 7</th>
          <td id="p7d1"></td>
          <td id="p7d2"></td>
          <td id="p7d4"></td>
          <td id="p7d5"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
```

I want to save every block with `id` on localstorage. I know I can use `localStorage.setItem("p1d1", $('#p1d1').text());` to save these, but is there a better way to save all of these blocks without going like

```
  localStorage.setItem("p1d1", $('#p1d1').text());
  localStorage.setItem("p2d1", $('#p2d1').text());
  localStorage.setItem("p3d1", $('#p3d1').text());
```

through the whole thing? I need to call each of them by their id later on.

Thank you.

Comment: select all the tds and loop. seems like a waste to write each one individaully in localstorage

Comment: You realize that this is only going to be visible to the current user/browser......

Comment: If you are okay modifying your JSON structure then you can club them in one object.
Something like

    localStorage.setItem(root: { "p1d1", $('#p1d1').text(), "p2d1", $('#p2d1').text(),"p3d1", $('#p3d1').text()})

Comment: @epascarello That's what I meant to do! Thank you for pointing it out still

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `document.querySelectorAll('td[id^=p]')` to select all the `td` that has `id` that startsWith `p`.

```js
const tds = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('td[id^=p]'));

tds.forEach(td => {
  const id = td.id;
  const text = td.innerText;

  console.log(id, text);
})
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="top">
    <th></th>
    <th>Monday</th>
    <th>Tuesday</th>
    <th class="wed">Wednesday</th>
    <th>Thursday</th>
    <th>Friday</th>
    <th>Saturday</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="noedit" colspan="3"></td>
    <td class="noedit" id="block-b">Meeting</td>
    <td class="noedit" colspan="3"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Period 1</th>
    <td id="p1d1" tabindex=1>text of p1d1</td>
    <td id="p1d2" tabindex=2>text of p1d2</td>
    <td id="p1d3" tabindex=3>text of p1d3</td>
    <td id="p1d4" tabindex=4>text of p1d4</td>
    <td id="p1d5" tabindex=5>text of p1d5</td>
    <td id="p1d6" tabindex=6>text of p1d6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Period 2</th>
    <td id="p2d1"></td>
    <td id="p2d2"></td>
    <td id="p2d3"></td>
    <td id="p2d4"></td>
    <td id="p2d5"></td>
    <td id="p2d6"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <td class="noedit">Chapel</td>
    <td class="noedit">Meeting or Advisory</td>
    <td class="noedit">Advisory</td>
    <td class="noedit">Class Meeting</td>
    <td class="noedit">or Advisory</td>
    <td class="noedit">Break</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Period 3</th>
    <td id="p3d1"></td>
    <td id="p3d2"></td>
    <td id="p3d3"></td>
    <td id="p3d4"></td>
    <td id="p3d5"></td>
    <td id="p3d6"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Period 4</th>
    <td id="p4d1"></td>
    <td id="p4d2"></td>
    <td id="p4d3"></td>
    <td id="p4d4"></td>
    <td id="p4d5"></td>
    <td id="p4d6"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Period 5a</th>
    <td id="p5ad1"></td>
    <td id="p5ad2"></td>
    <td class="noedit" rowspan="4"></td>
    <td id="p5ad4"></td>
    <td id="p5ad5"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Period 5b</th>
    <td id="p5bd1"></td>
    <td id="p5bd2"></td>
    <td id="p5bd4"></td>
    <td id="p5bd5"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Period 6</th>
    <td id="p6d1"></td>
    <td id="p6d2"></td>
    <td id="p6d4"></td>
    <td id="p6d5"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Period 7</th>
    <td id="p7d1"></td>
    <td id="p7d2"></td>
    <td id="p7d4"></td>
    <td id="p7d5"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would store it in one key instead of tons of keys. Simple reduce statement can let you gather all of the data.

```js
var cells = document.querySelectorAll('td[id^="p"]')

function save() {
  const data = Array.from(cells).reduce(function (o, td) {
    o[td.id] = td.innerHTML;
    return o
  }, {})
  console.log(data)
  //window.localStorage("data", JSON.stringify(data))
}

function loadData () {
  var data = window.localStorage("data")
  if (data) {
    var obj = JSON.parse(data)
    Object.entries(obj).forEach( function (entry) {
      document.getElementById(entry[0]).innerHTML = entry[1]
    })
  }
}

save()
```

```html
<table>
        <tr class="top">
          <th></th>
          <th>Monday</th>
          <th>Tuesday</th>
          <th class="wed">Wednesday</th>
          <th>Thursday</th>
          <th>Friday</th>
          <th>Saturday</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="noedit" colspan="3"></td>
          <td class="noedit" id="block-b">Meeting</td>
          <td class="noedit" colspan="3"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Period 1</th>
          <td id="p1d1" tabindex=1></td>
          <td id="p1d2" tabindex=2></td>
          <td id="p1d3" tabindex=3></td>
          <td id="p1d4" tabindex=4></td>
          <td id="p1d5" tabindex=5></td>
          <td id="p1d6" tabindex=6></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Period 2</th>
          <td id="p2d1"></td>
          <td id="p2d2"></td>
          <td id="p2d3"></td>
          <td id="p2d4"></td>
          <td id="p2d5"></td>
          <td id="p2d6"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th></th>
          <td class="noedit">Chapel</td>
          <td class="noedit">Meeting or Advisory</td>
          <td class="noedit">Advisory</td>
          <td class="noedit">Class Meeting</td>
          <td class="noedit">or Advisory</td>
          <td class="noedit">Break</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Period 3</th>
          <td id="p3d1"></td>
          <td id="p3d2"></td>
          <td id="p3d3"></td>
          <td id="p3d4"></td>
          <td id="p3d5"></td>
          <td id="p3d6"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Period 4</th>
          <td id="p4d1"></td>
          <td id="p4d2"></td>
          <td id="p4d3"></td>
          <td id="p4d4"></td>
          <td id="p4d5"></td>
          <td id="p4d6"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Period 5a</th>
          <td id="p5ad1"></td>
          <td id="p5ad2"></td>
          <td class="noedit" rowspan="4"></td>
          <td id="p5ad4"></td>
          <td id="p5ad5"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Period 5b</th>
          <td id="p5bd1"></td>
          <td id="p5bd2"></td>
          <td id="p5bd4"></td>
          <td id="p5bd5"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Period 6</th>
          <td id="p6d1"></td>
          <td id="p6d2"></td>
          <td id="p6d4"></td>
          <td id="p6d5"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Period 7</th>
          <td id="p7d1"></td>
          <td id="p7d2"></td>
          <td id="p7d4"></td>
          <td id="p7d5"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend adding a class to each cell:

```
<tr>
  <th>Period 1</th>
  <td id="p1d1" tabindex=1 class="periodCell"></td>
  <td id="p1d2" tabindex=2 class="periodCell"></td>
  <td id="p1d3" tabindex=3 class="periodCell"></td>
  <td id="p1d4" tabindex=4 class="periodCell"></td>
  <td id="p1d5" tabindex=5 class="periodCell"></td>
  <td id="p1d6" tabindex=6 class="periodCell"></td>
</tr>
```

Then doing something along the lines of the following:

```
$('.periodCell').each(function(index, elem)
{
    localStorage.setItem(elem.id, elem.textContent);
});
```

you could do some other things with the selector so that you're not needing to add the class to every cell, but this is the most basic option...

another is regex on the cell ids... but that would be pretty painful